# Solving Lagrange multipliers question

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve this question using lagrange multipliers. pls help me see if i am doing it correctly.

$$f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$$
$$g(x,y,z)=xyz=1$$

$$f_x=\lambda g_x=2x=(yz)\lambda$$
$$f_y=\lambda g_y=2y=(xz)\lambda$$
$$f_z=\lambda g_z=2z=(xy)\lambda$$

i obtained 4 points here I would like to know if the points i have obtained are correct or are there more to it? Also is this a min or max since they are all the same?
$$f(1,1,1)=3$$
$$f(1-,1,-1)=3$$
$$f(-1,1,-1)=3$$
$$f(-1,-1,1)=3$$

Comment: According to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=min%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%29+subject+to+xyz%3D1), you've found the global minimum of $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$. You can use intuitive method by assigning the values of $x,y,z$ that satisfy $xyz=1$, let the values be $x=1, y=0.5, z=2$, then $f(1,0.5,2)\approx5.25$. This isn’t a rigorous proof to determine whether $f(x,y,z)$ has a minimum  or maximum value, but it's very useful as the first step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All are minumum. Think in the geometric interpretation of $f$: distance$^2$(point of surface,origin).

Comment: are there any more points to be obtained?

Comment: @JakeMitch. You found all of them.

Comment: See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%3D1%2Fxy.

Comment: how does the wolfgram works?

Comment: See the **surface** $xyz=1$.

Comment: so instead of the function i just input the constraint into wolfgram? how do i input 2 or more constraints?

Comment: Thing again in my answer: $f$ is dist^2 of point of $xyz=1$ to the origin.

Comment: sorry i don't get what you mean

Comment: $d((x,y,z),(0,0,0))=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I thought this was an intriguing picture so I'll post it. Red sphere touches blue surface at three points, (fourth point is seen on rotation ). The other surfaces shown:    $ x = yz $ , $ y = xz $, and $ z = xy $ are in  (yellow, pink , gray).